# How to make native scrollbar of a table view visible while Voiceover accesibility is kept on in Swift4(iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift4, accessibility, voiceover

Native `scrollbar` is not visible when **VoiceOver** is kept on for a `tableView`. Scrolling down doesn't show the `scrollbar` though `tableView.isScrollEnabled` is set to `true`.

Comment: can you provide trial code.

Comment: Besides code snippets, would you mind providing some screenshots to realize your problem?